# How to obtain spectrogram of a 3D accelerometer file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, signal-processing, accelerometer, spectrogram

Here is my code, But it doesn't work

Load the dataset

```
dataset = np.loadtxt("filename", delimiter=",")
X = dataset[:,0:5]
Y = dataset[:,5]
```

compute spectrogram

```
N = 1e5
amp = 2 * np.sqrt(2)
noise_power = 0.001 * X / 2
time = np.arange(dataset) / X
freq = np.linspace(1e3, 2e3, N)
x = amp * np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*time)
x += np.random.normal(scale=np.sqrt(noise_power), size=time.shape)
```

Compute and plot the spectrogram.

```
f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(x, X)
plt.pcolormesh(t, f, Sxx)
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.show()
```

this is a part of my dataset

```
33,4.9106E+13,-0.6946377,12.680544,0.50395286
33,4.91061E+13,5.012288,11.264028,0.95342433
33,4.91061E+13,4.903325,10.882658,-0.08172209
33,4.91062E+13,-0.61291564,18.496431,3.0237172
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to obtain spectrogram of a 3D accelerometer file in python?

Comment: My code doesn't work.

Comment: I think you have to share a couple of lines of your data file before anyone can help. Also why do the spectrogram yourself, why not just use the mpl built in [specgram](http://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/specgram_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-specgram-demo-py)? btw, you have actually not stated what is not working as you expect...

Comment: i know the mpl built in function but i didn't know how to use it with my dataset

Answer (score 0):

Your posted data does not have headers, so I'm guessing that your last 3 columns is actual acceleration, the first column is of no interest and the second column is symbolizing time. However if that is the timesignal you are sampling at what frequency?

You still have not really explained what is not as you expect, however it seems like you try to make a plot with several different channels. As far as I know one makes a spectrogram on one signal only.

Here is how I would treat similar data as you have, although I had to fake all data so that it becomes somewhat meaningful plots.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# faked data with noise & trends, with assumption of which column is what
fake_size = int(1e4)
time = np.arange(fake_size)/1000 # 1kHz
# your dataset[:,1] ?
base_freq = 2 * np.pi * 100
x = np.sin(4*base_freq*time) + 0.2 * np.random.random(fake_size)
# your dataset[:,2] ?
y = np.sin(2*base_freq*time) + 0.1 * np.random.random(fake_size) - 0.05 + time
# your dataset[:,3] ?
z = np.sin(3*base_freq*time) + np.sin(1.5*base_freq*time)+ 0.1 * np.random.random(fake_size) - 0.05
# your dataset[:,4] ?

xyz_magnitude = x**2 + y**2 + z**2

to_plot = [('x', x), ('y', y), ('z', z), ('xyz', xyz_magnitude)]

for chl, data in to_plot:
    plt.figure(); plt.title(chl)
    plt.specgram(data, Fs=1000)
    plt.xlabel('Time [s]'); plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
```

This will quickly give a picture of what the frequencies are in these spectras, however if you are truly chasing relative magnitudes and or phases, you will have to do additional math as well as plots. Please note that your visual impression of the frequencies are dependent upon magnitude, so if you for example do `np.sqrt` on the `xyz_magnitude` the plot will not look exactly the same.

Comment: thnx alot for your reply it helps me.. but i want to ask a question!... x, and z in your code is a created signal ? if so, how to add my text file signal in each axis?

Comment: is generated* signal ?

Comment: the comment # your data... is intended as guesses for assigning your data, i.e. `x = dataset[:,2]` etc., it's a guess because you did not provide any headers for the columns, so only you know which data is in which column, my assumtion is that your actual dataset has `x` in the 3rd column. Your pasted data does not seem to hold any channel with time in seconds, which will work anyways with `plt.specgram`, however you will need to know the actual sampling frequency in order to end up with correct scaling, both on the x & y axis in the plot.

Comment: when i write for example x = dataset[:,2] to get the third column in x it gives me the following error Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\hadeer.elziaat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 7221
    Z = 10. * np.log10(spec)
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10

Comment: apparantly you end up in a state where you divide by zero, that is something that you will have to figure out why, but it's either the content of your data or the shape/size of x/y/z, i.e. x.shape should print like (m,). Some hints: a) is the content in dataset one to one with the textfile? b) do you have enough data to do the specgram with (for the fft-window)?  c) if a & b are ok, then you can try to find what part of the signal is causing the error and remove that before plotting.

Comment: sorry but i have another question.. my dataset have 1415684 rows, but the output of the xyz_magnitude spectrogram is 359470 rows!!.. i couldn't understand why the output of the spectrogram isn't equal to the number of rows of the original dataset? and what is the number of columns should the output of the spectrogram have?

Comment: I suggest that you read some general theory around specgrams, how they are made and then specifically what mpl actually uses to do the plot, and what you have as result from a specgram plot. You will then understand why.